# How to write a data into database using outputstream UTF-8

Tags: java, gwt

```
        System.out.println("record:::" + recordXML);
        URL url = new URL(Constants + tableName + "/update?commit=true");
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        System.out.println("insertorupdate");
        os.write(recordXML.getBytes());
        os.flush();
```

here where i put the UTF-8 chracter support

Answer (score 1):

You can use an OutputStreamWriter.

```
    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    OutputStreamWriter ow = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
    ow.write(recordXML); // Note: don't use getBytes() here
    ow.flush();
    ow.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this(Assuming recordXML is String)

```
 os.write(recordXML.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```